# Tennis ball in a glass of water

Tags: everyday-life, surface-tension

If you pour water into a glass half full and put a tennis ball there it would aim to its sides. But if you pour water completely full a ball would aim to center.

It's definitely related to a surface tension: when a glass is not full water surface is concave, and when a glass is full it's convex. So a ball aims to highest regions. Why does he do it?

Here's the video illustrating it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4ZATwHfheQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's definitely related to a surface tension

That is correct.

Surface tension means that the total surface area wants to be minimised.

[image: Ball in glass.]

Although the water surfaces aren't very well drawn, the surface is slightly concave in the half filled glass, slightly convex in the brim filled glass. The presence of the ball reduces the total surface area.

As a result, in the half filled glass total surface area is minimised when the ball is near the edges but it the brim filled glass surface area is minimised when the ball is dead centre.

Comment: Great! Let's try to understand it "more locally". We know that pressure under a convex/concave surface of water differs from pressure under it according to a Laplace's formula. So as we can see from your picture, in a concave case this difference of pressures sucks a ball to a side. But why it pushes it to a center in a convex case?

Comment: Because (hydrostatic) pressure is a little higher at the top of the 'hill'.

Comment: Maybe lower? It seems reasonable. But consider an energy argument. Water surface area increases when a ball deviates from a center. So a surface energy is the least when a ball in on the top of the hill. So there should be a force pushing it there. This is actually your answer. But this reasoning doesn't use hydrostatic pressure.

Comment: Because my answer doesn't involve an equation of motion. I only state why the end-state is what it is, not how you get from ball-in-the-centre to ball-at-the-edge in time. The vid clearly shows there's acceleration, so that means there's force. But *don't ask me* to calculate that force because I don't know how to. :-)

Comment: Hydrostatic pressure is definitely slightly higher just below the surface of the top of the 'hill': $p=p_0+mgh$ (Pascal's law).

Comment: Actually, I thought of calculation of that force in some approximation :), write down the equation of motion and compare theoretical period with experimental one. But let's talk a bit more about your answer. It says that this is a surface tension that pushes the ball to the center. The argument: it's trying to minimize the area. But it seems there's another argument that a surface tension should pull the ball out of center, because due to a surface tension the pressure inside is greater than the pressure outside the water. This looks like a contradiction.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps pressure plays a part too. But I don't see a contradiction, as towards the edges hydrostatic pressure would be a bit higher too. So both effects would push in the same direction, not contradict each other.

Comment: Hydrostatic pressure is less towards the edges. And contradiction is that pressure on wet part (blue) of a ball is greater than on a dry part (green) when a surface is convex: http://i77.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0609/cd/b6b1d72200057433852f261b5a6cbecd.png And it's less when a surface is concave. Actually I'm starting to think that your explanation is wrong. And the real reason is wetting, which causes a force normal to a surface. In a concave case both effects (wetting and pressure difference caused by a curvature of a surface) push the same way. But in a convex case they push in a different ways.

Comment: How do you conclude hydrostatic pressure is lower towards the edge? In the part-filled glass the fluid meniscus is slightly elevated. So just below the surface pressure is slightly higher than in the centre. The same is true for the  centre of the of the brim-filled glass. Re. wetting, I can't see how it can provide the force to push the ball from the centre to the edge.

Comment: Hydrostatic pressure is lower towards the edge in a case of the brim-filled glass. It's precisely your argument: $\rho g h$ plus Pascal's law. I'll write the answer about wetting soon.

Comment: Regarding wetting: it would be easy to test whether it plays a role: does a wax(ed) ball (which "repels" water) behave the same way, or will it stay in the middle in the half filled glass and go to the side in the full glass.

Answer (score 1):

Area of a base of a spherical cap of a height $h$ is $S = \pi (2Rh - h^2)$. This is the value water surface decreases as the ball dives in. This means that according to the principle of virtual work the force water sucks the ball in is
$$
F_{suck} = \frac{d}{dh} \sigma S = 2 \pi \sigma (R - h),
$$
where $R = 2$ cm is a ball's radius, $h \approx 1$ cm -- immersion depth, $\sigma \approx 0.072$ N/m -- surface tension of water against air. It's almost vertical, but directed towards the center of curvature (towards the edge when the surface is concave and towards the center when the surface is convex).

Let us assume that the surface has spherical form with the radius of curvature $R_{curv}$ of order of a meter. Let $\alpha$ be a (small) angle between the line from the center of curvature and a ball center and the vertical. $F_{suck}$ is constant in the first order by $\alpha$. Then projection of Newton's second law to the horizontal is
$$
m R_{curv} \ddot \alpha = - F_{suck} \alpha,
$$
where $m = 2.7$ g is the ball mass.
This is the equation of a harmonic oscillator with period
$$
T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{m R_{curv}}{F_{suck}}} \approx 4.8 \text{ s}.
$$
Which is reasonable. The experiment shows that the time ball moves from the edge to the center (quarter of the period) is of the order of a second. Then damping becomes important.

Comment: +1 You mean centimeters when you say $R=2sm$,  (i.e. it should be $R=2{\rm cm}$) right? You might also want to say that you're using the method of virtual work in the first equation. There will  be a deformation of the water's convex surface too, and you haven't taken it's change in energy into account, but it's very interesting that you get the right period, so this tells us that the deformation of the water's "main" surface is not the dominant change in total energy (this is meant to be a comment, not a criticism: I don't know without doing a great deal of thinking how one would account ....

Comment: .... for all the surfaces.)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your remarks. Surely it's approximate reasoning. It's straightforward but very tedious to take into account the deformation of the "main" surface if we consider it as spherical, but it seems to be the excess of precision. Actually, this is the sphericity of the surface and it's radius of curvature that are main approximations. And it's hard to estimate how big mistake it gives.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance:  *"but it's very interesting that you get the right period"*. I disagree. The numbers for $h$, $R_{curve}$ and $m$ are all plucked out of thin air. Also, watch the video and see if you can see any oscillation, please. This is dismissed as "Then damping becomes important" but water isn't very viscous at all. I've done some experiments and can't for the life of me see any oscillation going on. Will run some more experiments with lower surface tension tomorrow.

Comment: @Gert. $m$ and $R$ are mass and radius of a standard table tennis ball: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_tennis#Ball $h$ can be easily measured precisely. But we don't need such precision and it can be seen by an eye that it's about $0.5$ cm. (It also can be calculated from equating Archimedes' force with gravity force.) $R_{curv}$ is really a bit of plucked out of air. As the assumption of sphericity itself -- the surface is not spherical. It's rough appraisal and it'd be great if it would be correct right up to the order (as it is).

Comment: As for oscillations, I've done the experiment -- there's a clear pattern of damped oscillations.

Comment: @vanger Yes I agree: although the surface curvature is a bit plucked out of the air, by the same token I think we can safely say that the order of magnitude is right. I think your numbers are wholly reasonable. I'm not so sure about your last sentence, but whether or not there is oscillation at the edge is irrelevant as far as I can tell (this could simply be the tennis ball bouncing off the edge having hit it): the main point is that the transit time you have calculated is in good keeping with observation.

Comment: Some (hand-waving) arguments about the order of $R_{curv}$. 1. Characteristic size of the glass is 10 cm. $R_{curv}$ is definitely more, but less than two orders (spherical cap with such $R_{curv}$ would be too flat).

Comment: 2. If we assume sphericity of the cap of water, let's calculate it's volume. $V_{\text{spherical cap}}=\frac13 \pi H^2(3R_{curv}-H)\approx \pi R_{curv}H^2$, where $H$ is the height of a cap which is of order of 1 mm. But as seen by an eye, it's almost cylinder with the height of approximately 1 mm. So $V \approx \pi a^2 H$, where $a$ is the radius of a glass (4 cm in my case (just like the ball)). Equating the volumes we get $R_{curv} \approx \frac{a^2}{H} = \frac{(4 \cdot 10^{-2})^2}{10^{-3}} \text m = 1.6 \text m$.

Comment: Will respond tomorrow evening.

Comment: I believe you're onto something but I think your equation of motion is wrong. The full solution for an oscillator like that would be: $\alpha=\alpha_0\cos\omega t$, with $alpha_0$ the initial ($t=0$) angle. Start off in the middle ($\alpha_0=0$) and you have no oscillation. Start off at a small $\alpha_0$ and the ball would start moving toward the centre! Also, I cannot see any oscillation in my experiments at all.

Comment: It would also, I think, need another term: $-mg\sin\alpha \approx -mg\alpha$ on the right, which would shorten the period.

Comment: General solution has the form $\alpha(t)=\alpha_0 \sin(wt+\phi_0)$. And yes, if you start in the middle ($\phi_0=0$) there would be no motion, and if you start off with some $\phi_0 \ne \pi k$ the ball would start moving towards the center, as should be. As for seing oscillations, it's highly damped oscillator. It survives just a bit more than a period. It's clearly observable for a usual cup with diameter of about 2 tennis balls, brim-filled with a cup (the higher the cup - the better).

Comment: I don't think that we need that term. Gravity force is vertical, but that equation is protection of eq. of a central of mass motion to the horizontal. One may argue that $F_{suck}$ actually depends on $\alpha$ 'cause of non-flatness of the surface, but that perturbation is $O(\alpha^2)$. BTW, I thought about why the deformation of the "main" surface is inferior to the perturbation from the ball itself. It's straightforward to see in the spherical approximation I use that it's impact is order below.

Comment: About last comment about neglecting the Archimedes' force which is not completely vertical. I did some calculations and came to that it's $O(\alpha)$ but still negligible. I can write it down if you're interested.